# Unexpected Warning: inline function used but never defined

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, g++

I searched online for the similar warnings; most people run into the similar warning because they defined the inline function in another translation unit (e.g. the cpp file).

But I put the definition within the same unit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

template <typename T>
struct MagicInt { constexpr static const char* str(); };

template <>
struct MagicInt<int8_t> {
        constexpr static const char* str() {
                return "123";
        }
};

template<typename T>
inline char* foo(char *buf, T t) {
        if (t < T(5)) return (char*)memcpy(buf, MagicInt<T>::str(), strlen(MagicInt<T>::str())) + strlen(MagicInt<T>::str());
        return buf;
}

int main() {
    char buffer[1024];
    buffer[0] = '1';
    buffer[1] = '0';
    std::cout << foo(buffer, uint16_t(123)) << std::endl;
}


$ g++ -Wall iwarn.cpp -o iwarn -lrt -std=c++0x -O3
iwarn.cpp:5:48: warning: inline function ‘static constexpr const char* MagicInt<T>::str() [with T = short unsigned int]’ used but never defined [enabled by default]
 struct MagicInt { constexpr static const char* str(); };
                                                ^
```

My gcc version:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)
```

It looks to me that gcc was looking for the definition of `MagicInt<uint16_t>::str()`.

I can think of 3 ways to fix it:
1. defining `MagicInt<uint16_t>::str()`, tho it will never be called
2. providing a default implementation (in addition to the partial template specialization)
3. suppress the warning?

Which one is cleaner?  Which one generates less code (probably #4 -- ignoring the warning)?

Comment: How about removing the code that is never called?

Comment: @BoPersson I actually compacted the actual code.  memcpy() indeed is executed in some cases.  Just not in my example.  Thanks

Comment: *"it will never be called"* from `foo` definition, we cannot say that.

Comment: You give 3 options and then say "probably #4"

Comment: @M.M it is a sarcastic suggestion as if it were indeed the right choice, the compiler should have changed its warning? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the compiler is looking for the definition of `MagicInt<uint16_t>::str()`.

The reason it is doing so is

- The call of `foo(buffer, uint16_t(123))` (with result streamed to `std::cout` is an exact match for the templated `foo<uint16_t>()`.   Since you have explicitly forced the second argument of `foo()` to be of type `uint16_t` that should not be surprising.
- To instantiate `foo<uint16_t>()` (for which the template parameter `T` is `uint16_t`) the compiler must instantiate `MagicInt<uint16_t>`.  If it does not, it cannot compile the statement

> ```
>    return (char*)memcpy(buf, MagicInt<T>::str(), strlen(MagicInt<T>::str())) + strlen(MagicInt<T>::str());
> ```

The fact that `main()` has passed `uint16_t(123)` is irrelevant.   The instantiation of the template above is based on the type (`T`) of the function parameter, not the value passed.   The exact same logic as above would be used if `main()` instead did;

```
int main()
{
    char buffer[1024];
    buffer[0] = '1';
    buffer[1] = '0';
    uint16_t v;
    std::cin >> v;
    std::cout << foo(buffer, v) << std::endl;
}
```

because it is the type of `v` that matters in instantiating the template, not the value passed (regardless of whether that value is hard-coded - expressed as a literal - or determined at runtime (like I have done here)).

The simple ways to fix the problem are to define the functions being instantiated.  Either of your options 1 and 2 will do that job.

Option 3 (assuming it is possible - I haven't checked) will suppress the warning but - in a typical "compile-link" toolchain, the typical result will be a linker error - because `MagicInt<uint16_t>::str()` will still not be defined.

The real solution is to adjust your expectations.   The definition

> ```
> template<typename T>
>   inline char* foo(char *buf, T t) {
>     if (t < T(5)) return (char*)memcpy(buf, MagicInt<T>::str(), strlen(MagicInt<T>::str())) + strlen(MagicInt<T>::str());
>     return buf;
> }
> ```

is required to treated as if the value of `t` is unknown at compile time.   In other words, the compiler is not required to go through a sequence of detecting that the value passed is `uint16_t<123)`, determining that `t < T(5)` is always `false`, and then not instantiating `MagicInt<uint16_t>`.

Comment: Thanks for your input and yes, #1 and #2 work.  #3 also works and doesn't result in a linker error actually (at least for GCC's default linker). I am just curious which one is the best practice (probably #2), and which one produces the most compact code (probably #3).

Comment: You're asking for some universal "best" answer, as if there is such a thing.   It depends on how you expect to reuse the templated functions (e.g. is it at all possible you'll call `foo(buffer, uint16_t(2))`?) in which case worrying about compactness of code in your specific example (with a particular implementation) is irrelevant, since `MagicInt<uint16_t>` will need to be instantiated and `MagicInt<uint16_t>::str()` will need to be defined - in which cases options 1 and 2 are simply alternative implementation choices.

Answer (score 1):

If your argument is const expression, you might provide it in template parameter:

```
template<typename T, T t>
std::enable_if_t<(t < T(5)), char*>
char* foo(char *buf) {
    return (char*)memcpy(buf, MagicInt<T>::str(), strlen(MagicInt<T>::str()))
         + strlen(MagicInt<T>::str());
}

template<typename T, T t>
std::enable_if_t<!(t < T(5)), char*>
char* foo(char *buf) {
    return buf;
}
```

or in C++17

```
template<typename T, T t>
char*
char* foo(char *buf) {
    if constexpr (t < T(5)) {
        return (char*)memcpy(buf, MagicInt<T>::str(), strlen(MagicInt<T>::str()))
            + strlen(MagicInt<T>::str());
    } else {
        return buf;
    }
}
```

Then `MagicInt<std::uint16_t>::str()` wont be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have specialized the template for `int8_t` but you are using `uint16_t`. The `uint16_t` version of `MagicInt` was never defined.

Comment: yes, I agree (just that I didn't format my post properly -- MagicInt<uint16_t>::str() becomes MagicInt::str().  So I am looking for suggestion to see which way is better to fix.